# Can I expect one chapter per html file in an Epub?

Tags: epub, html, formatting

Is this the rule or can I find several chapters in an html file?
Having 1 chapter helps moving back and forth chapters or set bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is a valid file if there are several chapters in one file. You can even have the whole book as one HTML file.

The [epub spec](http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-overview.html#sec-content-docs) says

> Each Rendition of an EPUB Publication contains one or more EPUB Content Documents

Book marks can be made to a point in the file so don't need separate files.

Readers have a limit to the size of the HTML file and I think that is a reason to split the files.

Again with movement in the files it depends on the reader. Having smaller files might well help the reader as it can cache a whole file